# Is there a way i can make a counter in batch?

Tags: batch-file, time, counter

So basically, I’m trying to make a code in BATCH that counts infinitely to show how long a computer has been running. How do i do it?

I inputted:

```
@echo off
:loop
set /a sec+=1
echo Computer Runtime:
if %sec% geq 60 set /a min+=1
if %min% geq 60 set /a hrs+=1
echo %hrs%:%min%:%sec%
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
goto loop
```

I got a window that ended itself instead.

I expected a running window that DID NOT end.

Comment: `%min%` isn't set for the first 60 iterations, so line 6 gets read as `if  geq 60 set /a hrs+=1`, which is a syntax error.

Comment: additionally, `if %sec% geq 60` will also set the minute + 1 for each iteration of seconds above 60, so 61 will have minute 2, 62 will have minute 3 etc. Your seconds will also not reset to 1, it will continue from 60 upwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmmm... This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"
set /A hrs=0,min=100,sec=100

echo Computer Runtime:
:loop
set /A "sec=(sec-99)%%60,min+=^!sec-100,hrs+=min/60,min=min%%60+100,sec+=100"
set /P "=%hrs%:%min:~1%:%sec:~1%!CR!" < NUL
timeout /T 1 /nobreak > NUL
goto loop
```